# SwiftUI NavigationView nested in PageTabView wrong aligned on first appear

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

The NavigationViews inside my PageTabView are wrong aligned on first appear.
When i scroll to another page on my PageTabView and go back to the first page, the alignment is correct.
The content of the navigationview (red) is beneath the navigationbar on first appear.

[Image of first appearance of the NavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vl1.png)

[Image of the second appearance of the NavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7oB.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                NavigationView {
                    Color.red
                        .navigationTitle("\(index). Page")
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

Edit:
I want to build the layout of the rooms tab in the apple home app in compact mode. Therefore the TabView in the code above gets wrapped in another tabview without the pagetabviewstyle modifier.
This works, but the same extracted problem in the code above happens.

Comment: Both the images are same

Comment: sorry i uploaded the same image twice, now i uploaded the right images

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: I used this Pager Framework: https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                    Color.red
                        .navigationTitle("\(index). Page")
                }
                
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
```

Just moved NavigationView outside, it fixed the problem

Comment: thats not what i want to achieve. i need a navigationview for each of my pagetabview pages, that scrolls with the pages.

i want to get the layout of the rooms tab of the apple home app on iphones.